# How to click radio button of DEMOQA practice form

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
gender_xpath=f'//input[@name="gender"][@value="{row["Gender"]}"]'
gender=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,gender_xpath)
gender.click()
```

With this above code , I am not able to click on the Radio Button of this form https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form. Its throwing error

'selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable at point (578, 460). Other element would receive the click: ...'

Any possible solution would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'label' tag overlies the input you are trying to click on.

Try clicking the parent div:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
gender_xpath=f'//input[@name="gender"][@value="{row["Gender"]}"]/parent::div'
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, gender_xpath))).click()
```